# RegisterHotKeys and global keyboard hooks?

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

What are `RegisterHotKeys` and global keyboard hooks, and how do they work?

I want to make a key to get focused on my application's Form (when it's minimized) and then focus on a textbox, so from what I've read I need to use the `RegisterHotKeys` function (that's a better solution for my needs), but i couldn't find how or where I can choose my own key (only one key - <kbd>ESC</kbd>) and then command it to focus on my form, and then on the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample on how to use hot keys.

```
class myform : Form
{
    public myform()
    {
        RegisterHotKey(Handle, id, modifiers, mykey);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x312) // this is WM_HOTKEY
        {
            Show();
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
btw what key is 0X312 ? 
Thanks!
Amit

Comment: 0x312 is not a key, its the WM_HOTKEY message. the key is the virtual key codes which you register with RegisterHotKey.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx

Comment: Andrew hi, thank you very much. but, i didn't "got there yet",
RegisterHoyKey(Handle, id???, modifiers, mykey??)
I've a barcode reader, i configured it to "press" the ESC key, then send the barcode and then "press" enter.
i want my program to identify the ESC "Press" and then show the form and then focused on a textbox(these two commands i know how to do it), there is a way to register a hoy key without a modifier(Null is good?)
you gave me that great page, but i don't know what to write in id and in mykey, the function ask for int(uint?)
Thanks a lot in advance!!
Amit