# onKeyPress event do not work if a textbox in form has autocomplete?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a form with `keypreview` `true`. `OnKeyPress` (if key is escape) I was closing the form.

Later I set `autocomplete` with the first text box in form. Autocomplete is working but `OnKeyPress` event is not working now. If cursor is not in text box having auto-complete `OnKeyPress` works and still close the form on escape key.

Please guide how I can have both ? `Autocomplete` with closing form on escape.

Answer (score 2):

In your application you should not use form events for closing (because any control on your form can handle `OnKeyPress` by it's own and swallow it), you should register the hotkey.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey (int hwnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey (int hwnd, int id);
```

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563849/registerhotkeys-global-keyboard-hooks-c) or to [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.RegisterHotKey)