# c# Delete key for listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox where i can delete items with a button but i want to also be able to delete with the delete key on my keyboard, I could not find a way on google so can someone please help me

**Edit**
Its a winform application

This is the code for the delete button:

```
private void Button3Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = this.GetCurrentApplication();

    if (application == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Application selected");
        return;
    }

    if (MessageBox.Show("You are about to delete application: " + Environment.NewLine + _applicationListBox.SelectedItem + Environment.NewLine + "Are you sure you want to delete the application?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application will not be deleted.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else if (this._applicationListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        int index = _applicationListBox.SelectedIndex;

        _toepassingIniFile.ToePassingen.Remove(application);
        if (index == _toepassingIniFile.ToePassingen.Count)
            --index;
        application = index < 0 ? null : _toepassingIniFile.ToePassingen[index];

        _toepassingIniFile.Save(application);

        _applicationListBox.DataSource = null;
        _applicationListBox.DataSource = _toepassingIniFile.ToePassingen;

        _applicationListBox.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

**Answer thank to Jonesy**

```
private void ApplicationListBoxPreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode ==Keys.Delete )
        {
           deletefromlistbox();
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
        {
            Refreshapplication();
        }

    }
```

Refreshapplication

```
private void Refreshapplication()
    {
        var newapplication = new NewApplication(_toepassingIniFile);
        if (newapplication.Run())
        {
            _applicationListBox.DataSource = null;
            _applicationListBox.DataSource = _toepassingIniFile.ToePassingen;
            _applicationListBox.SelectedIndex = _toepassingIniFile.ToePassingen.Count - 1;
            _controllercombobox.DataSource = null;
            _controllercombobox.DataSource = _controllerIniFile.Controllers;
        }
    }
```

Comment: add a previewkeydown event to the listbox.  Then verify the key was Delete in the event handler

Comment: Can you give some more context? Installed application? Web application?

Comment: Its a winform application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855657/keyboard-shortcut-for-a-button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
applicationListBox.PreviewKeyDown +=new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(applicationListBox_PreviewKeyDown);
```

then

```
void applicationListBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        //delete
    }
}
```

then do like msm8bball said and abstract out that code so both button click and previewkeydown call the delete method

Comment: It wasnt completly correct the correct answer should be in the question but thanks to you i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Abstract out your logic for the deletion into it's own function. Have Button3Click call this function.

Then, add a new function that handles deletion, and have it also call the new function. Use this event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpreviewkeydown.aspx