# How to create shortcut keys for different buttons in c#.net?

Tags: c#

i am new to c#.net and programming ...please help to solve this problem

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F10)
            {
                Start();
            }
        }

        private void button2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F11)
            {
                Speak();
            }
        }

        private void button3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F1)
            {
                Skip();
            }
        }

        private void button4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F12)

                Repeat();
            }
        }
```

First shortcut key F10 is working but other shortcut keys are not working...how to enable other keys.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855657/keyboard-shortcut-for-a-button). Hope this help.

Comment: Your button has to have focus for these events to fire. This is not the way to do it.

Comment: Looking at signature event handlers, this Windows Forms application.
In this case, you can create a main menu items that assigns shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override ProcessCmdKey() in your Form like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch(keyData)
        {
            case Keys.F10:
                Start();
                return true;
                break;

            case Keys.F11:
                Speak();
                return true;
                break;

            case Keys.F1:
                Skip();
                return true;
                break;

            case Keys.F12:
                Repeat();
                return true;
                break;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

}
```