# What is keyboard hook?

Tags: keyboard, window, keyboard-shortcuts, touchpad

I was reading the Doc of Autohotkey and then I was not able to understand the meaning of the phrase 'keyboard hook' or 'mouse hook'.

this is the text:

"*The $ prefix has no effect for mouse hotkeys, since they always use the mouse hook. It also has no effect for hotkeys which already require the keyboard hook*"

URL: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - A **Keyboard Hook** or **Mouse Hook** that Means: that you can monitor/receive all the keyboard keypress values or that you monitor all the mouse button press values

Note: you will need to use the command code `#InstallKeybdHook` to enable the monitor

And for the **Mouse Hook** you will need to use the command code `#InstallMouseHook`

try this AHK Code:

Example.ahk

```
#SingleInstance force
#InstallKeybdHook

$^c::
send ^c
send {f5}
return

esc::exitapp
```

2 - And the $ prefix means that you can use the Hotkey ($^c::) into the same hotkey code (send ^c).

**How to Monitor All your Keyboard press values:**

1 - go to the System Tray.(Autohotkey Icon)

2 - then click right mouse button.

3 - then go to open.

4 - then click left mouse button.

5 - then click Ctrl+c

6 - Now you will see the 
     Keyboard Hook that
     you clicked.

[image: keyboard hook]

Note: For Monitor All the Keyboard KeyPress Values you will need to manually press the (F5) Key (Refresh)

Comment: In summary, `$` is to *avoid the infinite call loop* when calling self if without `$`. As the doc says 'The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect *prevents the Send function from triggering it*.' where `send` is probably calling `reg` key as Good Pen says instead of `hook` key which thereafter avoids the loop.

Comment: Also see https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/34274-how-do-you-send-a-comma/?p=216861

Answer (score 3):

## Type of hotkey (in autohotkey)

### a. reg

- reg: The hotkey is implemented via the **operating system**'s RegisterHotkey() function.
- reg(no): Same as above except that this hotkey is inactive (due to being unsupported, disabled, or suspended).

RegisterHotKey function (winuser.h)
[from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)

```
BOOL RegisterHotKey(
  [in, optional] HWND hWnd,
  [in]           int  id,
  [in]           UINT fsModifiers,
  [in]           UINT vk
);
```

### b. hook

- k-hook: The hotkey is implemented via the **keyboard hook**.
- m-hook: The hotkey is implemented via the mouse hook
- 2-hooks: The hotkey requires both the hooks mentioned above

## `keyboard hook`

it **monitors keystrokes**,  for the purpose of activating:

1. **hotstrings**
2. keyboard hotkeys not supported by RegisterHotkey
3. It also supports a few other features such as the Input command

### When keyboard hook is used

[here says:](http:////www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/121557-how-does-ahk-register-hotkeys/?p=688533)
The most **recently registered hook** gets called first.
The most **recently started script** doesn't necessarily take precedence, since **hook hotkeys always take precedence over registered hotkeys**.
AutoHotkey use the hook when:

1. instructed to use it (#UseHook or $),
2. automatically if the script uses **#IfWin**
3. if the hotkey **can't be registered**.

## Further reference:

### SetWindowsHookEx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks

To take advantage of a particular type of hook, the developer provides a hook procedure and uses the SetWindowsHookEx function to **install it into the chain** associated with the hook

### SetWindowsHookExA function (winuser.h)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN

### similar question about `C#`:

[RegisterHotKeys and global keyboard hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563849/registerhotkeys-and-global-keyboard-hooks)

### a

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=68550